# How to retrieve data from GridDB using a Python client?

Tags: griddb

I'm working on a Python project and need to fetch data from GridDB. Is there a Python client library available for GridDB? How can I retrieve data from GridDB using Python? Is there an official python client library or should I use JDBC driver using Java

I have tried searching for an official tool with documentation but unable to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the GridDB [docs](https://docs.griddb.net/gettingstarted/python/#installation) there you can see the example of building a client using python.
There is a repo with python client [here](https://github.com/griddb/python_client/)